# How to configure the mouse wheel to scroll between windows of the same group?

Tags: xfce, manjaro, mouse-gestures, window-switching

I'm more used to Unity and I really like the option of placing my mouse pointer over an opened application icon and scroll the mouse wheel to move between the application's opened windows.

In XFCE this still works but it also traverses between all opened windows for other applications, while I only want to change windows the application I'm pointing at.

For example if I have multiple Chromium windows opened and my IDE too. If I place the mouse's pointer over Chromium and scroll, the IDE windows will be shown if I scroll long enough, while I only need to switch between Chromium windows.

How can this be done please ?